# Make webview fill_parent stay above the bottom image in Android

Tags: android, layout

I have following things layed out in my xml file:

1. Webview
2. Bottom image/ Admob

Since I wanted my Admob to be displayed at the bottom, I chose two different layouts LinearLayout for Admob as suggested and RelativeLayout for other views.

Also, since I'm displaying splashscreen first and then webview, my logic goes such that I want both of them in a framelayout. My bottom image and Admob lay one above the other.
So, my code goes as:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/app.news"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/views"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/splash_screen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/splash_screen"
            android:visibility="visible"
    />

<WebView 
android:id="@+id/webvw"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
android:scrollbars="none" 
android:visibility="invisible"
/>

             <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/bottomImage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:visibility="visible"
    />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_alignBottom="@id/views"
>

<com.admob.android.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/ad"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
myapp:backgroundColor="#000000"
myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC"
myapp:testing="false"
/>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want webview to occupy all the space except for the bottom image, I'm not sure how to make it happen using webview height to be "fill_parent".

Answer (score 1):

Try using a zero height and set gravity to 1:

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
```

Comment: Setting webview height to 0dip is making the webview not appear/be visible.

Comment: But also you need to use LinearLayout with orientation="vertical". First it's child is WebView (or any nested layout containing it) with layout_height="0" and layout_weight="1". Second child is AdMob with layout_height="wrap_content"